# iOS: [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

Tags: ios, objective-c, setneedsdisplay, uiview-hierarchy

I seem to have forgotten the basics regarding this or perhaps I am just too tired.

I have a view controller and a view that is a subclass of `UIView` that is named MyViewClass.

In `viewDidLoad` of my viewController I `alloc` and `init` `self.myView` like this:

```
self.myView = [[MyViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0, 0}, 320, 480}];
self.view = self.myView;
```

At some time in my viewController, I would call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];`. No problem here.

I expose a property in MyViewClass.h:

```
@property(nonatomic) i;
```

The property `i` will be used in `drawRect` in myView;
So, from my viewController I would set it like so:

```
self.myView.i = 100;
```

So my question is:

Why am I able to call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` in my view controller without needing to call `[self.myView setNeedsDisplay];`and `drawRect` will be called in myView, but I can't just do `self.view.i` in my view controller as `self.myView` has been assigned to `self.view` already in `viewDidLoad` in my view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]`, but not `self.view.i` because `UIViewController`'s `view` property is of type `UIView`.

> self.myView has been assigned to self.view already in viewDidLoad

Remember that the actual assignment happens at runtime, while compiler errors are generated at compile time. The compiler has no idea in what order your view controller's methods may be called, so it can't make any guesses about the actual type of a property's value beyond the property's original declaration. As far as Xcode is concerned, `self.view` is just a `UIView`.

As danh suggested above, you can override the property declaration to inform the compiler that your view is of type `MyView`. Although, your approach of using the `self.myView` property may be preferred anyway: it allows you to change up the view hierarchy in the future without changing your interface, and doesn't muck with inherited methods. `UITableViewController` does the same thing: both the `view` and `tableView` properties return the same view instance, but the properties are typed differently.

It's important to remember that the type of a *property* is not necessarily the same as the type of its *value*. `self.view` may have been assigned to an instance of `MyView`, but the *property* is still of type `UIView`. Regardless of the type of object assigned to it, the property's accessor is still a method with return type `UIView`.

So, as far as the compiler is concerned, `self.view` is nothing more than a plain old `UIView`, even if you know that it isn't.

I think it would help to elaborate more on what properties are, and differentiate between the property and the instance. When you create a property like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong, nonatomic) MyView *myView;

@end
```

The compiler translates it into a variable, an accessor method (the "getter"), and a mutator method (the "setter"). The property is merely shorthand for declaring the methods like so:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    MyView *_myView;
}

- (MyView *)myView; // accessor / getter
- (void)setMyView:(MyView *)myView; // mutator / setter

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (MyView *)myView
{
    return _myView;
}

- (void)setMyView:(MyView *)myView
{
    _myView = myView;
}

@end
```

When you call `self.myView`, or `self.view`, you are actually calling the accessor method; it's equivalent to `[self myView]` or `[self view]`. What it returns is a pointer to an object in memory. Because you assigned `self.view = self.myView`, both properties are set to the same object; thus, both `self.view` and `self.myView` return a pointer to the same object.

To summarize:

- Assigning `self.view = self.myView` generates no compiler error, because `MyView` is a subclass of `UIView`. Note that assigning `self.myView = self.view` *would* generate a warning because `UIView` is not a subclass of `MyView`
- Calling `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` causes `myView` to draw itself, because the *same instance* is assigned to both properties. If you log the descriptions (`NSLog(@"view=%@, myView=%@", self.view, self.myView)`) for both properties, you can observe that they have the same memory address
- You cannot call `self.view.i` because the `view` property is declared to have type `UIView`, and `UIView` has no method named `i`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to enter a newline in my comment before I was finished. I added some more clarifications to my answer.

Comment: I think it's important to realize that `self.myView` is not doing the drawing, because `self.myView` is just a method. The object returned by `self.myView` (an instance of `MyView`) is doing the drawing. Even though self.view and self.myView are two different methods, they return the same object.

Comment: Technically, you can call `self.view.i` by casting `((MyView *)self.view).i` or calling `[self.view performSelector:@selector(i)]` or other more obfuscated means. It's just that Apple's compiler won't accept it, because the compiler is trying to enforce type safety.

Comment: Note: if you don't load the view controller's view from a nib, or assign it programmatically, `UIViewController` will create a view in its implementation of `loadView`. So your controller will always have a view.

Comment: The view shouldn't be assigned in `viewDidLoad` because the method means that the view has already been loaded. It's just not what the method was intended for. It's also bad practice to reassign the view once it has been loaded, because the original view may already be part of a view hierarchy; reassigning could leave the original view orphaned.

Comment: `loadView` is definitely the correct place to assign `self.view`. `viewDidLoad` is where you'd usually apply styling or other setup. `viewWillAppear:` is a good place to prepare the view for appearance by reloading tables, assigning labels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> In viewDidLoad of my viewController I alloc and init self.myView like this:

```
self.myView = [[MyViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0, 0}, 320, 480}];
self.view = self.myView;
```

Never never never do that in `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` means you already have a view. You should never ever change your view controller's view.

It is fine (and required) to set your view `loadView`. That is what it is for. But in `viewDidLoad`, absolutely not.

Comment: This strays from what I intended to ask in my question, but: what if I have no view (I deleted that, let say) in storyboard in my view controller and I am not setting up a view programmatically in my view controller, would it be filled automatically by the system a default view for my controller?

Comment: In addition to my comment above: "....You should never ever change your view controller's view.." The reason for this is? What sort of bad things would this cause doing so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to substitute the VCs view with a UIView subclass, have it work in all the usual ways, but also give the vc's code access to properties on the subclass?  I think you can get there by overriding the view getter:

```
- (MyView *)view {
    return (MyView *)[super view];
}
```

Also, you can setup the custom view in IB as the VC's view, so there's no need to do anything in loadView.

Comment: I'm thinking the compiler will complain about self.view.i because self view is of the abstract type.  This is why I suggest replacing the getter and let it do the cast for you.

Comment: Hmm.  Sorry to hear.  You mean you override the setter as I suggest, then say self.view.i = 100; then NSLog(@"%d", self.view.i); and it doesn't log 100?

Comment: please post the error/warning, and the line where it appears

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46460/discussion-between-danh-and-unheilig)